# Asp.Net MVC Dynamically Binding Many to Many entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having issues while creating the View for capturing many to many relationship.

Following are the models...

Model for which I want to create the View...

```
public class Service : Entity
{
    [ForeignKey("ServiceType")]
    public int ServiceTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ProviderAccountName { get; set; }

    public virtual ServiceType ServiceType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }// this thing right here I want to capture many Parameters dynamically added by the user

    public Service()
    {
        this.Parameters = new List<Parameter>();
    }
}
```

Now the real issue here is that the Parameter itself has its own CRUD operation Views and would be created from there. I just want to bind the parameters to Service entity that is being created, it would have been much easier if we had given a table with all parameters listed and check boxes allowing users to check the parameters he wants to include. However in my case the user has to have an Add Link clicking on which a new parameter row will be generated with Select2 autocomplete applied where in he can select that parameter.
I wonder if I can use BeginCollectionItem for this but am not able to figure out how to do so as when I tried, it gave me ModelErrors for required fields in Paramater, as if it is creating new Parameters to insert into DB...

The partial View for Editor is as under...

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Parameters"))
{
    <div style="width: 100%;">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CategoryID, new { @class = "ParamCategoryId" })
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ID, new { @class = "ParamId" })
        <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        <span id="paramDesc"></span>
        <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
}
```

I guess BeginCollectionItem won't help me here, additionally there are more than few problems I am facing, as we can see I am using select2 plugin, have applied it using the classes to the elements, which is not working as expected, everytime a new row is generated all above rows values are reset to blank as 'initSelection' gets triggered.

Is there a better way of doing this, I feel might just have ended up complicating things...???

Comment: "it gave me ModelErrors for required fields in Paramater, as if it is creating new Parameters to insert into DB..." isn't that on purpose? You have marked the Parameters collection as virtual which indicates it's a navigation property. Therefore, when you insert your Service entity, the items in Parameters collection will get inserted too.

Comment: So do I need to change the Model then? What I need is to be able to dynamically add existing entities from the DB to that Service entity at the time of creation. Parameters that are already created in the Database are to be linked to the Service, I have created a many to many relationship with FluentAPI...

Comment: If there is a relation between Parameters and Service, you edit the Parameters in your view. Post the fields and you hit validation errors on Database insert/update, isn't it working correctly then? If you edit the Parameters collection of Service, then the related entities are updated in Parameters' table too.

Comment: If the problem is that Parameters are always inserting instead of updating (as in the relation already exists in database), you'll need to post the ForeignKey aswell. So I would assume you have something like [ForeignKey]ServiceID in your Parameter class. Include that too in your form as a hidden field.